# how to add a color hover on text when you're using the addClass function in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navbar that changes the color of the text (and the bg color, but I think this is not important now) when it scrolls to a certain point. When it reaches the point it changes the class (add/ remove). 
The problem comes now, i can't put another hover color on the text, it doesn't appear. I tried it in css, adding to the class the :hover propriety and in jq by using the .hover function, none of it works.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An ugly solution for this unclear question is to add !important on the css rule you add, it will override existing css you have.
I suggest using inspect element to see which classes you have on the element and see what styles are applied and are overridden at that point. If you see the style is not there you have a problem in your code not referring to the correct class if the style is overridden you should see why.